# Is it possible to make a Spring MVC web app run as a "standalone executable" with Java and Tomcat embedded?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, war

I have a web app built with Java, Spring MVC, and JDBC.  The result is a WAR file.

To run it, the user has to install Java 8 JDK and Tomcat, and deploy the WAR file to the Tomcat server.

It would be great if they could just download the one file run it as a standalone application.

That is, run "the WAR file" and just browse to http://localhost:8080/myapp

Also, on Windows it would be great it was setup as a Server (like Tomcat is when installed with the installer).

Is there any way to do this?  Maybe with Spring Boot or something new like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, Spring boot is the way to go.
It allows you to build an executable Jar with all dependencies and a Tomcat (by default, can be changed) embedded.
But users will still need to download a JRE to execute the Jar, and a database if it's required, but you can use en embedded database like H2, HSQLDB..., depends what is your needs.

Comment: Thanks -- do you think it's easier to add the new parts to my existing Eclipse/Spring/Maven project, or should I start with a new Spring Boot project from scratch and migrate the code over?

Comment: @Elliot.Easton.2020 It's always easier to start directly with Spring Boot but you still can add Spring Boot to your Spring project. There is a lot of resources like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration

Answer (score 1):

Yes . you can use spring boot to achieve your results. Kindly refer the below link for sample code
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use embedded jetty server using maven but that would require you to setup few things your app and may have align your existing app, please check this [article](https://steveliles.github.io/setting_up_embedded_jetty_8_and_spring_mvc_with_maven.html) for more information.

Jetty is similar to tomcat server in terms of running spring application, there are not much difference in terms of development. Tomcat is just more famous.

Other option as others said, is to migrate your app to spring boot which would be easy if you already have app written in spring (But that depends how much code you have and how much time you have)